# EF code first created a column on DB table that does not exist in my model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I didn't find any question here that addresses this problem specifically, so here it goes.

I'm using EF Core Code First. One of the tables generated by EF migrations has an additional column that does not exist in my model. It might have existed, as I can see in the ModelSnapshot file, but it was removed a long time ago.

This entity does not have any complex object apart from the identity user and all other properties are primitive. (strings, ints, etc)

I have already tried to add that same field and generated a migration and it appears empty.
Then I tried to remove the field from the model and generated the migration again to see if now it recognizes I am removing it, but again.. migration empty.

I am thinking of removing it from the DB manually but the problem is that it still exists in the model snapshot file, which can generate other sync issues.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Most likely there is something in your model which is causing EFC to assume such column by convention. What type of column are we talking about? If its is "Discriminator", the something is wrong with generic type arguments of the base `IdentityDbContext`. If it is Foreign Key like, then look in other entities having navigation property to the entity in question. Note that if adding the property explicitly does not change migration, then it already existed as shadow property. If you want more concrete help, please provide more info about the field in question.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev 
You are right. Thank you for your answer.
By convention, it was creating a FK because on the "parent" entity I had the following code.

`public List<StockTransaction> StockTransactions { get; set; }`

I didn't pay much attention before because I had a similar code that was not generating the shadow column on the HistoricDividend table. The difference is that this has no set property..

`public List<HistoricDividend> HistoricDividends { get; }`

Thank you!